# my bootstrap website's mobile version isnt working

Tags: mobile, twitter-bootstrap-3

for some reason bootstrap isnt making my website (https://dylantn.github.io/Dusic/) automatically mobile compatible because i checked this website on my phone and it is just a zoomed out version of the desktop version

some one pls help

im frustrated
and need help

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ind.css">
  <title>Dusic-The Free Music Player Worldwide.</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-nav-demo" aria-expanded="false">
              <span class="sr-only"><font face="arial"></font>Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
          <a href="#" class="navbar-brand"><font face="arial"><span  class="navimg"><img src="dusic4.gif"  width="80" length="80" alt=""></span></font></a>
      </div>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-nav-demo">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                  <li><a href="#"><font face="arial">About</font></a></li>
                  <li><a href="#"><font face="arial">Contact</font></a></li>
              </ul>
  
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                  <li><a href="#"><font face="arial">Sign Up</font></a></li>
                  <li><a href="#"><font face="arial">Login</font></a></li>
              </ul>
          
          </div>
              
      </div>
  </nav>
  </div>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <div id="content">
          <h1><b><a href="#"><img src="dusic4.gif"  width="250" length="250"></a></b></h1>
          <h3><b>The Best Collection of Music That Ain't Worldwide...... MAN</b></h3>
          <hr>
        </div>
      </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
    <h1>What is the purpose of Dusic?</h1>
    <p>Our Society already has many music players, but i thought we need another one to clutter your life, plus it is Free!!</p>
    <br><h3>IT IS FREE!! THAT IS THE ONLY COOL FEATURE ABOUT THIS THAT SEPERATES THIS FROM EVERYTHING ELSE<br>YIPEEEEE!</h3>  
  </div>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the following tag `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1 maximum-scale=1 user-scalable=no" charset="utf-8">` to you `head` section.
You can find more info about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Comment: ok on the hosted website version, the hamburger menu doesnt work but in the local file the navbar works, do u have any knowledge in this area, i added the <meta> tag u wrote in my code

Comment: If you open Developer console in Chrome, you will see that you have js errors on your page. You need to fix them and probably hamburger menu starts working after it, anyway it's hard to say without seeing details about your code.